# Pass received token from one service to another

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I have this fairly straightforward use-case:

- Resource owner uses my Angular client to obtain a JWT token from IDP
- Angular client calls Service A (WebAPI) with the access token issued by IDP
- Angular client calls Service B (WebAPI) with the access token issued by IDP

I would like to support the following scenario:

- Have Service A act like the Angular client and pass-through the access token it received to make a call to Service B

So basically, Service B can be called either directly by the Angular client or by Service A. In both cases, it must be provided a Bearer token in order to access any of the WebAPI endpoints.

From Service A, I do not know how to store the provided token so that later on when I need to use the `HttpClient` to call Service B I can set the `Bearer` header.

Comment: Can you elaborate why do you need to store the token server-side? Do you need to execute requests without user intervention (e.g. scheduled tasks)?

Comment: Assume that Service B provides some functionality that Service A depends on. So when the user calls Service A, I would like to call Service B using the same token (from Service A). So basically Service A uses the token for what it needs and then passed through the token to Service B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your requirement is to call the second API (**Service B**) as part of a single request to **Service A** from an authenticated user.

If this is the situation, then I believe there is no reason to store the token server-side, and you may just take the `Authorization` header from the current request and reuse it to call **Service B**.

Some code may help explain what I mean, assuming `ControllerA` is a **Service A** controller:

```
public class ControllerA : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFromB()
    {
        var token = Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;

        MyModel result = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://serviceb/controllerb/actionb");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyModel>();
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. I didn't realize that the OWIN middleware kept the authorization information. Thank you!